# Change ASP.NET MVC master page based on culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a requirement to change the master page used based on the current culture. I can do this fairly easily by overring View, OnResultExecuting or OnActionExecuting and this works fine for the majority of my pages.

My problem is that I have several views that do not use master pages and I obviously do not want to set the master page for these views. I am having trouble finding out in code if a view has a master page - masterName is null or emtpty string in all cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel{MasterPage="SomeMaster"};
    returnView(model);
}

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/Views/Shared/<%= model.MasterPage %>" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

This way if you don't have a master page defined it will not change it :)

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks.